# Gulp jekyll browser-sync rebuild loop

Tags: npm, gulp, jekyll, reload, browser-sync

I have been using a Gulp script on my Jekyll project together with browser-sync and some other plugins (to minify/concat JS/Sass and to minify images and svg).

Starting a few days ago (I'm not sure what caused it, using my old gulp scripts doesn't help) it's causing a loop of 2-15 reloads every time I save a HTML or JS file.

This returns in the following in the terminal:

```
[00:51:47] Finished 'jekyll-build' after 850 ms
[00:51:47] Starting 'jekyll-rebuild'...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[00:51:47] Finished 'jekyll-rebuild' after 241 μs
[00:51:47] Starting 'jekyll-build'...
      Generating... 
                    done in 0.188 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
[00:51:48] Finished 'jekyll-build' after 881 ms
[00:51:48] Starting 'jekyll-rebuild'...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[00:51:48] Finished 'jekyll-rebuild' after 480 μs
[00:51:48] Starting 'jekyll-build'...
      Generating... 
                    done in 0.251 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
[00:51:49] Finished 'jekyll-build' after 826 ms
[00:51:49] Starting 'jekyll-rebuild'...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[00:51:49] Finished 'jekyll-rebuild' after 942 μs
```

My Gulpfile looks like the following. Sorry for pasting so much code in here.

```
/**
 * Build the Jekyll Site
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);
    return cp.spawn('jekyll', ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
        .on('close', done);
});

/**
 * Rebuild Jekyll & do page reload
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-rebuild', ['jekyll-build'], function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

/**
 * Wait for jekyll-build, then launch the Server
 */
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['sass', 'jekyll-build', 'jekyll-rebuild', 'imagemin', 'svgmin'], function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: '_site'
        }
    });
});

/**
 * Compile files from _scss into both _site/css (for live injecting) and site (for future jekyll builds)
 */
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('_scss/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: ['scss'],
            onError: browserSync.notify
        }))
        .pipe(prefix(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
        .pipe(rename({
            extname: ".min.css"
        }))
        .pipe(uglifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/css'));
});

/** optimize images **/

gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
    return gulp.src('assets/img/*')
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngquant()]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./_site/assets/img'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
});

gulp.task('svgmin', function() {
    return gulp.src('assets/svg/*.svg')
        .pipe(svgmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./_site/assets/svg'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        '***scripts***' //removed for readability
        ])
        .pipe(include())
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: function(err){
                notify('JS compile error: ' + err);
            }
        }))
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('javascript'))
        .pipe(rename({
            extname: ".min.js"
        }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('javascript'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
        .pipe(notify('JS Compiled'));
});

/** Lint JS **/

gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src('javascript/app/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

/**
 * Watch scss files for changes & recompile
 * Watch html/md files, run jekyll & reload BrowserSync
 */
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('_scss/**/**/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('assets/img/*', ['imagemin']);
    gulp.watch('assets/svg/*', ['svgmin']);
    gulp.watch('javascript/app/*.js', ['lint', 'scripts']);
    gulp.watch(['*.html', '**/*.html', 'javascript/main.js', '_layouts/*.html', '_includes/**/**/*.html'], ['jekyll-rebuild']);
});

/**
 * Default task, running just `gulp` will compile the sass,
 * compile the jekyll site, launch BrowserSync & watch files.
 */
gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Does anyone see something that could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the line in your watch function is too broad:
`gulp.watch(['*.html', '**/*.html', 'javascript/main.js', '_layouts/*.html', '_includes/**/**/*.html'], ['jekyll-rebuild']);`

The second one - `'**/*.html'` I think is seeing any sub folders, which would include the _site folder, so it sees all the changes there and gets stuck in a loop. You change a file, it regenerates, the _site folder gets dumped, it sees that, regenerates, etc etc.

**edit to excluded _site folder**
If you have a lot of subfolders and want to include them with `**/*.html` try excluding the _site directory by adding `'!_site/**/*'` to the list.

Also, keep in mind that you are specifying .html, that will not pickup any markdown files.

Working on this question has led to this - I think this will be my new watch (I have no reason not to watch all files, other may not want this):

`gulp.watch(['**/*.*', '!_site/**/*', '!node_modules/**/*','!.sass-cache/**/*' ], ['jekyll-rebuild']);`

the first part seems to watch everything, the second part excludes the site folder and everything in it, then the same for node_modules and .sass-cache.. So far I have not been able to break it, and this is much simpler than what I had:

```
gulp.watch(['./*', '_layouts/*', '_videos/*', 'order-online/*', '_includes/*', '_posts/*', '_sass/*', 'css/*', 'services/*', '_data/*' ], ['jekyll-rebuild']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you're moving me in the right way. How do you make sure the _site folder doesn't get included? I have quite a few subfolders that include separate index.html files. I could of course point to the folders separately, but it would be cleaner to exclude _site.

Comment: I know pointed to all my folders separately instead of using `**/*.html` and it indeed stops looping! If you know about a way to exclude the _site folder that would be great, otherwise I'll accept your answer tomorrow.

Comment: try prepending _site with ! to exclude that subfolder. I'll edit my answer to include that.